# How to create an MFP push notification adapter using Java only (no Javascript)

Tags: java, push-notification, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to make an IBM MobileFirst Platform push notifications adapter fully in Java and XML (no Javascript), for EventSource Push Notifications.

All the what I found is a small paragraph and code in [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_java_server_side_api.html).

What is the equivalent of the following Javascript code in Java?

```
WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name: 'PushEventSource',
    onDeviceSubscribe: 'deviceSubscribeFunc',
    onDeviceUnsubscribe: 'deviceUnsubscribeFunc',
    securityTest:'PushSecurityTest'
});
```

Sharing eclipse project will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event Source-based push notifications is not currently supported if using Java adapters.

Feature enhancement requests can be submitted here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help

Comment: Thanks @Idan.
I would be happy if Java adapters can behave in the same way as Javascript ones.

Comment: Is the answer above applicable to all types of Push notifications? (Tag, Silent, ...)

Comment: No. Only for Event Source.